# SQL Developer - automatically refresh a query

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to automatically refresh my own query in Oracle SQL Developer?

Something like Tools/Monitor Sessions.../Refresh but for any provided query.

Comment: if you're fine with a CLI, the REPEAT command will give you exactly what you're looking for in Oracle SQLcl (it's in your SQLDev bin directory) https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/04/sqlcl-run-a-query-over-and-over-refresh-the-screen/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, turn your query into a user defined report.

[image]

You can right-click on your query result grid in the worksheet -

[image]

Then if you want a new one, i'd just keep the one and edit the report properties for your new query.

[image]

Doesn't have to be a grid either - you can have a report of type script. Or use charts. [Or a lot more](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/04/oracle-sql-developers-best-kept-secret-reports/).

Comment: Works, but is there a way to run a report on a database while the connection is busy executing another query? (Unshared report?)

Comment: run your long running queries on unshared worksheets whenever possible, otherwise you'd have to create a new connection